# Dimensions of logo causing branding difficulties

Tags: logo

I am working on a logo for a company called `unstack` on a pro-bono basis.

The company will provide short instructional videos on programming concepts.

I have produced the first logo for them, but I have been told that the dimension may cause some branding issues.

[image]

As a result, I have thought about merging the `unstack` element and the `u`. But that would make it wider.

[image]

I was just wondering how people generally deal with such problems? Especially given the breadth of print and digital mediums available? What suggestions would you have for my design so it fits a more square of spherical shape.

Comment: Looks quite close to stackoverflow logos idea. Do you really want this? Because web icons are square you should strive to be squarer, i agree. So wider may be better.

Comment: They would likely be sued by StackOverflow for this logo if they gain any sort of acclaim.

Comment: Are you asking others to tell you how to design it "more square"? That's a bit broad and opinion-based. You *clearly* have some rep at SO.. so uhm... yeah. that appears to be where it's idea sprang from. Even if not intentionally.. seeing it for 10k rep sunk in.... scrap this, start over.

Comment: You could make the U wide enough that the stack will fit right inside it… thereby making the following lawsuit even more certain. I would walk away from this design, fast.